# Encrypt/Decyrypt - Cipher - JceSecurity Restriction

Tags: encryption, aes, jce

I am trying to encrypt/decrypt the data using javax.crypto.Ciper where I have given transformation as AES/ECB/PKCS5Padding.

My problem is when I run the code in Local machine, encryption / decryption works fine, however when I run the same code on Server, system throws Exception during Cipher.init("AES/ECB/PKCS5Padding").

On doing detailed analysis and checking the code inside Cipher.java, I found the problem is inside the following method [Cipher-initCryptoPermission()](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/javax/crypto/Cipher.java#Cipher.initCryptoPermission%28%29) when system checks for JceSecurity.isRestricted().

In my local machine, JceSecurity.isRestricted() returns FALSE, however when it runs on Server, the same method returns TRUE. Due to this on server, the system does not assigns right permissions to the Cipher.

Not sure, where exactly JceSecurity restriction is set. Appreciate your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On doing deep-diving I found the real problem and solution.

Under Java_home/jre/lib/security there are two jar files, local_policy.jar and US_export_policy.jar. Inside local_policy.jar, there is a file called default_local.policy, which actually stores all the permissions of the cryptography.

In my local machine the file had AllPermission, hence there were no Restriction in JceSecurity for me and was allowing me to use AES encryption algorithm, but on the server it is having limited version as provided by Java bundle.

Replacing the local_policy.jar with no restrictions (or unlimited permissions) did the trick.

On reading more about it on Internet found that Java provides the restricted version with the download package as some countries have restrictions on using the type of cyptography algorithms, hence you must check with your organisation before replacing the jar files.

Jar files with no restrictions can be found on Oracle (Java) site at following location.[Download link](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jce-6-download-429243.html)